# How to connect a scrollbar to two canvas with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have to create an application that use a data base to show a list of users and their informations in function of the parameters entry. There is two type of informations, first one the obligate informations and the free informations.

I create four canvas, two on the top for the titles of those type like user, lastname, firstname... and two more below for the contents. There is a lot of users so i have to put a scrollbar that control the two canvas below but I dont find how to connect one scrollbar to two canvas.

I have try to create a function but it don't work. here is the code.

```
def scrollbarCommuneVertical():


      canevas_tab_gauche.yview
      canevas_tab_droite.yview

fenetre_principale = tix.Tk()

# a canvas to contain all the others

canevas_tableau = Canvas(fenetre_principale, width=100, height=100, bg="grey")

# the two canvas on the top

canevas_titre_tab_gauche = Canvas(canevas_tableau, width=600, height=50, bg="grey")
canevas_titre_tab_droite = Canvas(canevas_tableau, width=550, height=50, bg="grey")

# the two canvas on the bottom

canevas_tab_gauche = Canvas(canevas_tableau, width=600, height=50, bg="grey")
canevas_tab_droite = Canvas(canevas_tableau, width=550, height=50, bg="grey")

# I use frame but I am not sur it is important

frame_tab_gauche = Frame(canevas_tab_gauche, bg="grey")
frame_tab_droite = Frame(canevas_tab_droite, bg="grey")

canevas_tab_gauche.create_window((4, 2305), window=frame_tab_gauche, anchor="sw")
canevas_tab_droite.create_window((4, 2305), window=frame_tab_droite, anchor="sw")

canevas_tab_gauche.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,600,10000), yscrollcommand=scrollbar_vertical.set)
canevas_tab_droite.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,600,10000), yscrollcommand=scrollbar_vertical.set)

scrollbar_vertical = Scrollbar(canevas_tableau, orient=VERTICAL)  
scrollbar_vertical.configure(command=scrollBarCommuneVertical())
```

Comment: put your two frames in one new `Frame` and then put this frame on canvas - you will need only one canvas and you will have to assign Scrollbar to only one canvas.

Comment: see [TreeView](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have another problem, because I have 4 canvas, canvas 1 and 2 have to be scroll together in horizontally but canvas 2 and 3 have to scroll together vertically